# Understanding JSON conversions in flutter, NodeJS and Cloud Functions. Facing major issues in code

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Here is the code I use in my flutter app to send JSON data to my server written in nodejs:

```
    if (DEBUG) print('*: ' + jsonEncode({'order': Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getOrder().toJson()}));
   http.Response response1 = await http.post(
    Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getsubmitOrderURL(),
        headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   "charset": "utf-8"
                 },
        body: jsonEncode({'order': Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getOrder().toJson()})).timeout(
            Duration(seconds: 10),
                onTimeout: () {
                     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(
                            'Server timeout. Please try again'), duration: Duration(seconds: 3)));
                                setState(() => busy = false);
                                return;
                              });
```

The print statement above shows me how data is going and look something like this:

> *: {"order":{"restName":"Food","restAddress":"32 abc street,UK","restPostcode":null,"time_accepted":null,"time_ready":null,"time_dispatched":null,"table_number":34,"delivery_discount":null,"total":10.2,"subtotal":10.2,"delivery_fees":null,"menuOrderData":[{"id":"244","price":"4.45","name":"Cacik (v)","quantity":1,"topingsOrder":[]},{"id":"329","price":"5.75","name":"**Lamb's Liver**","quantity":1,"topingsOrder":[]}]}}

**------My nodejs server side --------**
Configuration:

```
const https = require('https');
const express = require("express");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/receiveOrder", async function (req,res) {...
  const data = (req.body.order); // Get ORDER Data
```

Once the processing after this is done. My server takes this data and stores it on firebase by calling a cloud function and the code responsible to send this is as follows:

```
const CFSdata = JSON.stringify({'order': data})
          console.log(CFSdata);
          //console.log('-----END----');
          const optionsCFS = {
            hostname: process.env.CLOUD_URL,
                port: 443,
                timeout: 5000,
                path: process.env.CLOUD_ORDER_SAVE_PATH,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/application-json',
                   'Content-Length': CFSdata.length,
                   'charset': 'utf-8'
                 }
           }
    const orderReq = https.request(optionsCFS, resCFServer => { // CREATE ORDER IN FIREBASE
                if (resCFServer.statusCode==200){ // do something }
            }
```

The data in console before going to cloud function looks like as follows:

{"order":{"restName":"Food","restAddress":"32 abc street,UK","restPostcode":null,"time_accepted":null,"time_ready":null,"time_dispatched":null,"table_number":34,"delivery_discount":null,"total":10.2,"subtotal":10.2,"delivery_fees":null,"menuOrderData":[{"id":"244","price":"4.45","name":"Cacik (v)","quantity":1,"topingsOrder":[]},{"id":"329","price":"5.75","name":"**Lamb's Liver**","quantity":1,"topingsOrder":[]}]}}

This above data goes to my cloud function and my cloud function looks like as follows:
Configuration:

```
const express = require("express");
app.use(express.json());
...

exports.saveOrder = functions.https.onRequest( async (req, res) => {
  console.log('-------------saveOrder Triggered----------------')
  let order;
  try{
    console.log(req.body)
    order = JSON.parse(req.body);
    //order = JSON.parse(req.body.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error is: ${error}`);
    console.log(`Order is: ${order}`);
    console.log('-------------saveOrder Triggered ERROR----------------')
    res.sendStatus(400) // Bad Request
    return
  }
```

The above console.log prints **<Buffer 7b 22 6f 72 64 ...**

This all works fine when normal english characters are use. But when characters like 'é à...' are used I get errors on My cloud function.

So for example if send:

> "name":"**Sautéet Lamb's Liver**"
> instead of
> "name":"**Lamb's Liver**"

I will get an error.

> Error is: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> Order is: undefined

Can anyone help me please as I am close to pulling my hairs out with this. Thanks

Comment: Fix incorrect header: `'Content-Type': 'application/application-json'` should be `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: When I do as above at my server side - I get `Error is: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` at cloud function end

Comment: Then remove `order = JSON.parse(req.body)` - body already parsed as json because of `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Yup, removed `JSON.parse(req.body)`. Working with normal characters but anytime something like this - ' é ' comes then `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse`

Comment: I don't see where you send `CFSdata`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the culprit is `CFSdata.length` - wrong size with diacritical characters. Try calculating length as:

```
(new TextEncoder().encode(CFSdata)).length
```

`Content-Length` parameter requires size in bytes, but [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-width character encoding. Since some letters like `é` are encoded in two bytes, a difference arises between string length and buffer size.

Comment: SO GLAD IT WORKED! Please could you explain what difference this code made and why it was not working with normal `.length`?